# Configuration from a subproject not autowiring

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to move my configuration from xml to java classes following this tutorial: [java based config](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/07/spring-dependency-injection-styles-why-i-love-java-based-configuration/); however, my configuration classes are in one sub project while I need to autowire from a bean in another...

Mainly: ApplicationConfig.java

```
    @Autowired
    private InfrastructureConfig infrastructureConfig;

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(infrastructureConfig.dataSource());
    }
```

I am trying to replace this block from applicationContext.xml in another sub-project:

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

but for some reason this is not autowiring:

```
     @ContextConfiguration(classes={StandaloneInfrastructureConfig.class,QAInfrastructureConfig.class})
     @ActiveProfiles("standalone")
     @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
     public class blahClass implements blahOtherClass {

          @Autowired
          JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

          public List<Blahs> loadBlahs(long id) throws SQLException, IOException {
              List<Blahs> blahVar = null;
              blahVar=blahThing(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource()).executeBlah(id);
              return blahVar;
           }
     }
```

Comment: How about showing a little more than 2 lines of the class where you're attempting to autowire.

Comment: fair enough...you know how it goes with trying to obfuscate stuff.

Comment: Your `blahClass` doesn't seem to be a valid autowiring target. Is there any `@Component` or `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` annotation present?

Comment: yes... on `@RunWith` modified above, no on `@Component`

Comment: What error are you getting ?